# How to make email delay in gmail?

Tags: gmail

How to make email dealy in gmail?

I want to add time limit while sending email in Gmail.

or like undo email option in Gmail..

Please help!!!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
From the Settings menu, choose the option for Settings.
From the Settings window, make sure the General tab is selected.
Look for the setting that says Undo Send.
Click the check box to Enable Undo Send.
```

Click the drop-box to set the Send cancellation period, meaning the number of seconds you have to prevent the email from being sent. You can choose 5, 10, 20 or 30 seconds.